# Getting warning "The source expression is always of pattern's type, matches on all non-null values"

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, resharper, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I am trying to use the new C# 7 pattern matching feature in this line of code

```
if (Customers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == CustomerType.Company) is Customer customer)
{
    ...
}
```

But for some reason Resharper/Visual Studio 2017 is giving me a warning under `is Customer` with the following message

> The source expression is always of pattern's type, matches on all
>   non-null values

But `customer` can also be `null` right? Can anyone please explain to me why it's given this warning?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: While there isn't a vastly better way to write this expression to just check for non-null values, ReSharper is telling you that if you already know that every element is a Customer, why are you explicitly asking it to check if it is a Customer? It basically says "This looks fishy". It doesn't say "This is wrong". To be honest, I think ReSharper is right. I too would wonder about this expression if I saw that `Customers` is a collection of `Customer`. It would be much clearer to simply explicitly check for non-null inside instead.

Comment: I would agree that this is a daft warning from R#. "...matches on all non-null values" is exactly what you want here, so it makes no sense for R# to warn you that your code will work the way you want it to. I'd suggest raising this as an issue on the [ReSharper Issue Tracker](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right!

ReSharper (not Visual Studio) is factually right, although I don't know why that would be a warning.

Although `Customers` is a collection of `Customer`, the use of `SingleOrDefault` hints that the value might be `null` which is not a `Customer`.

And nothing says that all values coming out of `Customers` are non-`null`.

Comment: On the other hand this is a convoluted non-null check, which is probably why ReSharper warns about it.

Comment: Why convoluted? The way I read it is "give me the customer that .... If one exists, put it in the customer variable".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is useful when you have a `int?`, for example. The check `if maybeId is int id { ... }` allows to not type `maybeId.Value` each time you use it. R# should definitely *not* warn in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The warning goes away if you replace `is Customer customer` with `is {} customer` (requires C# 8).

JetBrains [recommends](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PatternAlwaysOfType.html) this solution by the way, saying it has some advantages when you refactor the code.

But if you find the code more readable with exact types and you prefer letting the compiler fail when you change types (to force a review, for example) you can just disable the warning completely. Please note that the compiled code (both IL and JITted) will be the [same](https://sharplab.io/#gist:755747d1f50696bb0b43c88a62e3f240) in both cases.

Comment: `is var customer` doesn't do the same thing: it will also match null. So that's probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even expect that `var` vs. its inferred type are not always interchangeable. Thank you for the correction. Is this a documented feature?

Comment: It's mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#var-declarations-in-case-expressions) ("The var case matches null"). And yes, as far as I can tell, it's the only case where `var` and the explicit type are not interchangeable. IMO that's a serious design flaw.